# how to make panorama view?

Tags: html, panoramas

I need help. How do I make panoramatic view from an image?

[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0a/Kuhtai_Panorama_view.jpg/800px-Kuhtai_Panorama_view.jpg]

Comment: SO Is not a coding service. Please post something you have tried so we can help you edit it, but we are **not** here to code it for you.

Comment: Please review:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, do not use tags when your question contains nothing related to them.

Comment: I'm sorry, guys. I just wanted to know any method, how to do it :(

Answer (score 0):

Obtain a camera/phone which has a panorama feature. Read instructions on how to use this function. Enjoy taking panoramic pictures.

Comment: Hahahaha, I really didn't expect my answer to be accepted. I was kinda being a smart-butt. Thanks, though!